# Prove that $(X,d)$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ - metric space such that $A,B \subset X$ and $ X=A\cup B$ where $(A,d_{|A\times A}), (B,d_{|B\times B})$ are complete subspaces. Prove that $(X,d)$ is complete.

I think it should be obvious that the sum of the complete subspaces is complete, but nevertheless a few years ago this task was in an exam so I would like to know how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: If you have a sequence in $A\cup B$ then infinitely many members have to be in one of the sets $A,B$. Also use the fact that a Cauchy-sequence that has a convergent subsequence is already itself convergent.

Comment: @leoli1 Why are you posting an answer in the comments?

Comment: @leoli1 your tip helped me so if you post your comment as an answer I would be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. We want to show that $x_n$ converges. As $X=A\cup B$ infinitely many elements of $(x_n)_n$ and hence a subsequence have to be in one of the sets $A,B$. Without loss of generality assume that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ of $(x_n)_n$ contained in $A$. As subsequences of Cauchy sequences are again Cauchy, we see that $(x_{n_k})_k$ is a Cauchy sequence. By assumption $A$ is complete, hence $(x_{n_k})_k$ is convergent. This then implies that $(x_n)$ is convergent (In general a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence is itself convergent). Hence $X$ is complete.